# How to change title of Central Admin in Create by AutoSPInstaller

Tags: central-administration

In the top left hand corner of my Central Admin site seem to be a title that got set some home. I want to change it but cannot find any setting for this. What I am talking about is "SharePoint - InsiderDev" in the picture below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It should just be a matter of going to Site Settings -> Title, Description and icon and changing the title.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Site Settings** --> **Title, Description and Logo** and change the title to what you want.

Sorry, but I am unable to see the image you posted.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I was using the install script "AutoSPInstaller" which uses this method:

http://www.wictorwilen.se/sharepoint-2013-central-administration-productivity-tip

Comment: Your easiest bet will be to modify the Powershell script and change the title in there and re-execute it. The other option is to put a script editor webpart and modify the <div> property for that div tag <ms-core-brandingText>